# How to set checked items to React state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a quiz in a React app, and I am working on a specific question that allows the user to select multiple options via checkboxes. So far, for other questions that are only radio button options, I have been able to set the selected answer to the state just fine. But I am getting stuck on how I would do this for a question that is checkboxes. I need the state to be updated each time a checkbox is checked or unchecked. The code for this checkbox question is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "frontity";
import { GridWrap, GridRow, GridColumn } from "emotion-flex-grid";
import QuizCheckbox from "/src/components/quiz-checkbox";

import QuestionCommonContainer from "../question-common.style";

const Question3 = ({ actions }) => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({});

  const checkboxes = [
    {
      key: "checkBox1",
      label: "Back",
    },
    {
      key: "checkBox2",
      label: "Side",
    },
    {
      key: "checkBox3",
      label: "Stomach",
    },
  ];

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCheckedItems({
      ...checkedItems,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  return (
    <QuestionCommonContainer>
      <GridWrap>
        <GridColumn px={["l"]}>
          <GridRow wrap="wrap" justify="center">
            <GridColumn width={[12, 12, 12, 4]}>
              {checkboxes.map((item, id) => (
                <GridColumn pb={"l"} key={id}>
                  <QuizCheckbox
                    name={item.label}
                    label={<h5>{item.label}</h5>}
                    selected={checkedItems[item.label]}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </GridColumn>
              ))}
            </GridColumn>
          </GridRow>
        </GridColumn>
      </GridWrap>
    </QuestionCommonContainer>
  );
};

export default connect(Question3);
```

I am thinking that I need to either alter the handleChange function, but I am not completely sure if that's right or how I would need to change it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The first two comments helped. I think I am very tired lol. I see that the items are being added to state, but with a little glitch:

So I have 3 checkboxes. I added `console.log(checkedItems)` to the handleChange function so I can watch the behavior in the console.

I go to make my first selection and the console returns `Object {  }` ... an empty object, even though I have selected one item. I try to select a second item and the console returns

```
{
  "Side": true
}
```

which was the second selection. I am not sure why the first selection is not being included in the returned object.

Comment: I don’t get what the problem is. The code looks fine. What part is not working as intended?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code that you've got there? Here's a simplified version of it on CodeSandbox which is working just fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-fog-w4st6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I guess I've debugged enough now to answer my own question. The handleChange function was just fine, and I realized that I was not getting correct console logs because I had the console.log() in the wrong place.

Comment: Even if you put `console.log()` right after `setCheckedItems`, it will not reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix:

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    setCheckedItems(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: !prevState[name],
    }));
  };
```

I’m not entirely sure what’s wrong with your code, it looks alright to me. But if anything is broken, chances are the lib you use `"@baalspots/tmm-theme/src/components/quiz-checkbox"` is not behaving properly.

The above fix try to mitigate misbehavior of lib. If it doesn’t help, then you need to post more details. What exactly is broken? Any error message? Plus you need to post link to an online playground of you code somewhere, like codesandbox, so people can experiment.

Comment: I've updated my question if you wouldn't mind taking a look